# Is there a way to make a select push content down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a newby! I am using a jquery plugin (ddslick) in order to custom a select element using images and descriptions but I have a few problems. I would like to understand if there's a way to push content down when i click on it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebVoD.png

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="select-box pt-3 col-md-6">

                    <select id="myDropdown">
                        <option value="0" data-imagesrc="1small.png"> Facebook</option>
                        <option value="1" data-imagesrc="1small.png">Twitter</option>
                        <option value="2" selected="selected" data-imagesrc="1small.png">LinkedIn</option>
                        <option value="3" data-imagesrc="1small.png">Foursquare</option>
                        <option value="4" data-imagesrc="1small.png">Twitter</option>
                        <option value="5" data-imagesrc="1small.png">LinkedIn</option>
                        <option value="6" data-imagesrc="1small.png">Foursquare</option>
                        <option value="7" data-imagesrc="1small.png">Twitter</option>
                        <option value="8"  data-imagesrc="1small.png">LinkedIn</option>
                        <option value="9" data-imagesrc="1small.png">Foursquare</option>
                        <option value="10" data-imagesrc="1small.png">Foursquare</option>

                    </select>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean about "push content down"?

Comment: Look at the image posted. When I click on the select element the content goes outside of its container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add this CSS:

```
#myDropdown .dd-options { position: relative; }
```

**Demo**

```js
$('#myDropdown').ddslick({});
```

```css
#myDropdown .dd-options { position: relative; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ddslick@1.0.3/dist/jquery.ddslick.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="select-box pt-3 col-md-6">
      <select id="myDropdown">
        <option value="0" data-imagesrc="1small.png"> Facebook</option>
        <option value="1" data-imagesrc="1small.png">Twitter</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Some content</p>
```